# Using PDFObject to download pdf with dynamic filename

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdfobject

i'm trying to use  [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com) for my brochure what i want is for the user to **select** a vehicle and download the specific vehicle that she/he has chosen. here's my code:

```
<form method="get" action="">

  <div class="form-group"><h5>Model</h5></div>

  <div id="select-vehicle" class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option selected disabled> Select Vehicles</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" disabled class="btn btn-default">DOWNLOAD</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

and this is my working javascript:

```
var workers = ["86", "Altis", "Avanza", "Altis", "Camry", "Fortuner", "FJ Cruiser"
            , "Hiace", "Hilux", "Innova", "LandCruiser", "Prado", "Previa", "PriusC"
            , "Rav4", "Vios", "Yaris"];
        for(var i=0; i< workers.length;i++)
        {
        //creates option tag
          jQuery('<option/>', {
                value: workers[i],
                html: '2017' + ' ' + workers[i] + ' ' + '&#174;'
                }).appendTo('#select-vehicle select'); //appends to select if parent div has id dropdown
        }
          $('button').click(function(event) {
            var value = $( "select" ).val();
            $('form').attr('action', '../../vehicles/' + value +'/');
          });

        $('select').change(function(){
          if ($(this).val())
          {
            $("button").removeAttr('disabled');
          }
        });
```

i wanted to pass this `$('form').attr('action', '../../vehicles/' + value +'/');` to the PDFObject so that it will look for the right filename to download the file.

Comment: I have 2 questions 1- what the files name look like 2- how many select do you have in the page + forms

Comment: @Tarek.Eladly see my script. workers array thats the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DOWNLOAD THE PDF**:

`PDFObject` is for embedding a pdf in your page. For downloading the pdf you can just go to that pdf, but you need the pdf file name. You don't show the name of the pdf files, so here you have an example if file names are the same as the value of the select...

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $('select').val();
    window.open('../../vehicles/' + value + '/' + value + '.pdf','_blank');
});
```

**EMBED THE PDF**:

If you want to embed that pdf in the page using `PDFObject` (you don't need a `form`for this option, just the `select`), first create a container in your html to hold that pdf...

```
<div id="vehiclepdf"></div>
```

... and the invoke `PDFObject` when you click the button...

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $('select').val();
    PDFObject.embed('../../vehicles/' + value + '/' + value + '.pdf',"#vehiclepdf");
});
```

Comment: getting this error Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf:"http://link/to/file"

Comment: What option are you trying, download or embed?

Comment: how do i pass to create new web page for the pdf after the user clicks it?. its working but it's appearing below?

Comment: What option are you trying, download or embed?

Comment: download, i got it to appear in full browser. one problem i dont want to leave the page. i want to create a new window for the pdf . when the user clicks

Comment: Done! Try it now

Comment: not working . but the window.open does. i creates a new window. umm is it possible to open it on a new tab . just to avoid popup blockers

Comment: Apparently no.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript